# Calculus integration problem: $\int(\sec x)(\tan x)(1+\sec x)^{1/2}dx$?

Tags: integration

What's the integral of $(\sec x)(\tan x)(1+\sec x)^{1/2}$?
How do you solve this by integration by parts?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Use substitution $u=1+\sec{x}$ then we get $du=\sec{x}\tan{x}\,dx$

$$\int{\sec{x}\tan{x}\sqrt{1+\sec{x}}\,dx}=\int{\sqrt{u}\,du}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}(u)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C=\frac{2}{3}(1+\sec{x})^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

Comment: From the original post: "How do you solve this by integration by parts" ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are generally very few things you can do with roots in integrals. So typically, when you're faced with $\sqrt{\text{something}}$, you make the substitution $u = \text{something}$ so as to remove all of the complexity from underneath root to outside of it, and then try to work from there.

As the other answers have shown, this particular problem becomes extremely easy after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy substitution problem: $u=1+\sec(x)$.

By parts let $u=\sqrt{1+\sec(x)} dv=sec(x) tan(x)$ and then $du=\frac{\sec(x)\tan(x)}{2 \sqrt{1+\sec(x)}}$ and $v=1+\sec(x)$.

Then

$$\int \sec(x)\tan(x)(1+\sec(x))^{1/2}= (1+\sec(x))^{\frac32}-\frac{1}{2}\int \sec(x)\tan(x)(1+\sec(x))^{1/2}$$

Comment: why don't you just take $u=1+\sec{x}$?i think it would be more simple :)

Comment: @ARickoMaulidar I mentioned that at the beginning of my solution, but the OP asked explicitely for a solution involving integration by parts ;)